# On the limit of a sum equalling $\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I've been looking at the following sum:
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{8}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}-1}\right)$$
Which I have proved converges to $\pi$. My proof remains relatively simple. It goes as follows:

We begin by developing the following expression:
\begin{align}
S
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k}{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{4}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{4k}{n}-\frac{4k^2}{n^2}}\right)\\
&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1-\left(-1+\frac{2k}{n}\right)^2}\right)
\end{align}
One can notice that the expression within the limit is just the Riemann representation of the following integral:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1-\left(-1+\frac{2k}{n}\right)^2}\right)=\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$$
Which is simply the area of the unit circle in the top half of the plane, equalling $\frac{\pi}{2}$. hence we have:
\begin{align}
S&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1-\left(-1+\frac{2k}{n}\right)^2}\right)\\&=2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx=\pi\end{align}
My question to you is; if you were asked to solve this limit problem, how would you go about it? This is a purely recreational question and i'm curious as to whether there exists even more elementary and elegant ways to prove that this sum is indeed equal to $\pi$. I'm purely looking for beautiful proofs to this limit problem!

Comment: Your proof is sufficiently pretty, imho. The form of the sum lends itself to Riemann sums, so personally I would also go along the same lines.

Comment: Hard to beat convergence to a simple integral.

Comment: Very nice proof, I really like it!

Comment: I would switch to a Rieman integral as soon as possible, e.g. $$S=8\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac kn\sqrt{\frac{n}{k}-1}=8\int_0^1x\sqrt{\frac 1x-1}\; dx=8\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}\; dx\ .$$Now for the integral i would use an Euler substitution, or the rather artificial $x=\sin^2t$, with $t$ going from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Then $dx=2\sin t\cos t$, so we integrate $\frac 12\sin^2 2t$...